# I'm not receiving daily e-mail updates

Tags: support, email-notification

I have three stack overflow items that I never received updates for in the last few days. I have my preferences set to receive daily inbox updates to my gmail address but I didn't get any updates. I was viewing a SO question today and I saw that there was stuff in my inbox so that's how I noticed. Admins if you need more information you can e-mail me because I don't know if I'll receive an update when you reply to this bug. Thank you

Comment: I noticed the same. I just figured notifications are sent at the end of the day only if they haven't been viewed on SO itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked you user history records and you access SO very frequently, almost every day; in addition, your inbox notification email frequency settings is set to daily. Keep in mind that you get a notification email only if there are unread notifications in your global inbox at the time the scheduler sends out the emails.

If you want to be notified more frequently [set the inbox email frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/894506) to *every 3 hours*.

Comment: Thank you for checking but the problem is I'm not being notified at all. With my current settings if any notifications are unread for more than a day shouldn't I be getting e-mail updates?

Comment: Yes, and according to our logs the last time the system sent you such an email was on Jan 4th 9:29am for 5 unread items.